# Set minHeight in activity to webView

Tags: android, view, android-webview, css

im wondering, how set minHeight to webView in activity class, not in xml file. 
can i count for yours help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView has a "setMinimumHeight(int minHeight)" method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight(int)